# MySQL Errcode 2 - problems creating database directories

Tags: mysql

This doesn't seem far too specific, but somehow I cannot find anyone else with this problem (at least on stack and google). People have issues with errcode 2, but every thing I've seen is people having issues with mysql's tmp directory. I've tried changing that, and that's given no luck.

I've also made sure that the owner/group of the mysql "datadir" is mysql.

I'm assuming the cause of this is because I have recently moved the mysql datadir to my `/ssd` directory.

I have changed the datadir location after copying `/var/lib/mysql` to `/ssd` and have restarted mysql.

For `/var/lib/mysql`, I renamed the mysql folder to mysql-old, as that folder was no longer in use. Just in case, I created a symlink in place of it that points to the `/ssd/mysql` directory.

For context, I am trying to import an sql file and it seems it cannot create the data or directories themselves. Here is the full error:

`ERROR 1 (HY000) at line 33: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/changelog/changelog.MYI' (Errcode: 2)`

In this instance, I'm trying to import a database named `changelog`

Even after changing the datadir entirely, it still seems to want to write to `/var/lib/mysql` - Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to look into section [mysqld] in my.cnf or mysqld.cnf in /etc/mysql/ 
It could be either due to too many files being open or tmp directory having no permission for your user.
http://alvinalexander.com/mysql/mysql-cant-create-write-file-error-message

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar error message when trying to create a new database. The final solution is uninstall mysql and reinstall it again. Everything was fine. There are some corruption in the file which caused the errno 2.